# maven: building a war with uncompressed jars

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I am trying to have a project with packacking **war** where the jars are uncompressed. I thought it could be done like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <recompressZippedFiles>true</recompressZippedFiles>
                <archive>
                    <compress>false</compress>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However the recompressZippedFiles parameter seems to be ignored, as all the jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder are the orginal, and thus compressed, ones (no matter if I remove the `archive` element or not).

I know that the default of `recompressZippedFiles` is already `true`. But no matter if I specify it or not, the jars are the original ones. I don't get fresh ones.

Any ideas?

I was asked about my **use case**: That war is used on several machines with virus scanners (e.g. Kaspersky) which are looking into every file, also those in archives. I need to reduce the time the virus scanners need to do so (without changing the settings of those scanners).

Comment: you should be more clear, from your question it seems like you actually wanted `recompressZippedFiles` to `false`, `true` is its default value, hence no changes there.

Comment: No, I want the compressed jars to be unzipped and then zipped again without compression.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you like to do this? What is the reason for doing so?